# Why TexStudio for MacOS is not being installed?

Tags: latex

I tried to install TexStudio several times but every time it shows error. Error "macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware."

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Do you wish to get a notarized / signed copy of the code - you can reach out to the people that package it and ask they sign the code.

If not, you would need to do the checking yourself and perhaps relax the gatekeeper settings. Since you don’t specify anything about which version of the OS / which version of the program, hopefully this general guidance helps you research what step to take next.

Here is my advice - if you’re not sure how to figure out a security error or just don’t want to be bothered, it’s best to not relax security / GateKeeper. It is a significant bit of responsibility to add and you lose that protection for all software - not just for this, so be sure to re-protect with GateKeeper as soon as you run software that can’t be bothered to protect you from malware.

Also - you could have legitimate malware and be one step away from unleashing it. Be sure you have a backup before relaxing Apple security in case you have a tampered product you downloaded. Just because it came from the proper web site, doesn’t mean that web site or your network wasn’t compromised.

Comment: It's important to note that it's not an error you're seeing, but macOS functioning as it should; protecting you from malware.  @bmike points you in the right direction; reach out to the developers to *notarize* the App with Apple.  Short of that, if you know what you're doing you can, as he says, "relax" Gatekeeper to allow the software to be installed.  I this isn't your cup of tea, I personally don't recommend doing so and looking for another similar app that has been notarized - it's safer this way.

Comment: Tips for relaxing GateKeeper can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362018/macos-catalinav-10-15-3-error-chromedriver-cannot-be-opened-because-the-de

Comment: Great link @jayvdb since this question didn’t even list what version of macOS and the steps are a little different I didn’t put that in the body. [We’ve got a ton of SIP knowledge here as well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Sip).